# dtypes issue in pandas chunk read_csv

Tags: pandas

When running this code to load csv in chunk,

```
df_i= pd.read_csv(file1,   sep=',')
dtype0= df_i.dtypes
list01= pd.read_csv(file1,  chunksize=chunksize, dtype= dtype0, sep=',')
for df_i in list01:
  print df_i.dtypes
```

it returns only object based.

```
id                  object
chain               object
dept                object
category            object
company             object
dtype: object
```

instead of :

```
id                    int64
chain                 int64
dept                  int64
category              int64
company               int64
dtype: object
```

Is it a pandas bug/issue ?

Comment: It's not very clear what are you trying to achieve... Why do you have different # of columns for the same file?

Comment: i think `dtype` argument expects a dictionary, so try this: `dtype=dtype0.to_dict()`

Comment: This solves the issue, thanks, it needs a dictionnary.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record...

`dtype` argument of the [read_csv()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) function expects a dictionary: `{'col_name': <dtype>}`

so try to change:

```
list01= pd.read_csv(file1,  chunksize=chunksize, dtype= dtype0, sep=',')
```

to:

```
list01= pd.read_csv(file1,  chunksize=chunksize, dtype= dtype0.to_dict(), sep=',')
```